# How to add text into a textbox?

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I want to put a text into a Textbox in a Website, but I can't. 
The first input is successful, but with the   Error :

`"An error has occurred in the script on this page, object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'" ; "JSON" is undefined and another more..,` and the another one Parameter, when I want do the same, I can't.

How can I solve it?

Edit: in the Console shows: "Vector smash protection is enabled"

Thanks!

The Code:

```
 WebBrowser wb;
        public BrowserWindow()
        {

            int i = 0;
            Load += delegate
                 {
                     this.wb = new WebBrowser();
                     this.wb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                     this.Controls.Add(this.wb);
                     this.wb.Visible = true;
                    this.wb.Navigate("http://www.zzz.com/");
                     this.wb.DocumentCompleted += delegate
                     {
                         if (i == 0)
                         {
                             HtmlElement x = wb.Document.GetElementById("a");
                             x.InnerText = "b";
                         }
                         if (i == 1)
                         {
                             HtmlElement y = wb.Document.GetElementById("c");
                             y.InnerText = "d";
                         }
                     };


                 };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SetAttribute on the HtmlElement

```
wb.Document.GetElementById("a").SetAttribute("value", "bla bla bla");
```

Comment: I have put: wb.Document.GetElementById("a").SetAttribute("value", "b");

but i have the same result 

I have edited the question , because i found in the Console that it shows "Vector smash protection is enabled"

Comment: @TomaateTip can you give the real page URL?

Comment: the URL is www.lufthansa.com

Comment: Any Idea how can I add two or more text into a textbox??